# The topological nature of $y^2=\pm x$. Compact? Connected?

Tags: general-topology

> In $\mathbb{R}^2$, is the set $\{(x,y): y^2=\pm x\}$ compact or connected?

I think the set is two parabolas, meeting at origin. So, it is connected. But it is unbounded; so, not compact.

But the answer key says it's neither. I wonder how.

Comment: It's absolutely connected, for the reason you said

Comment: Unless some topology other than the standard one is being used...

Comment: No this is the complete question. We have a doubt clearing session tomorrow. So maybe I'll ask the teacher.